# querying using count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following database:

> Stocks (StockNo, Storecode, Description, Quantity, Units, Reorder,
>   Price, SuppCode)

This is a sample of the data contained within it:

```
STOCKNO STOREC DESCRIPTION             QUANTITY UNITS  REORDER   PRICE SUPPCO
------- ------ ----------------------- -------- ------ ------- ------- ------
    126 LEG    Sealing wax                    9 Box          5    7.99 S5
    127 LEG    Red binding ribbon            13 Roll        10    6.47 S5
    128 LEG    A3 cream notary paper         21 Ream        10    7.85 S5
    129 LEG    Coloured ink                  22 Bottle      10    3.48 S4
```

I need make a query to display the suppliers (suppcode) that supply at least 3 stores.

This I what I have so far:

```
select suppcode, count(distinct storecode) as StoresSupplied
from stocks
group by suppcode
having count(*) > 3
```

This produces the following results

```
SUPPCO STORESSUPPLIED
------ --------------
S3                  4
S4                  3
S2                  3
S1                  1
```

Check the whole table the results for S3, S4 and S2 are correct but I cannot find any reason why S1 is there. S1 appears on the table supplying 8 different items but to only 1 individual storecode.

Comment: What if you change `count(*) > 3` to `count(distinct storecode) > 3`?

Comment: `.......having count(*) > 3` ?

Comment: On a side note the predicate `at least 3` is equivalent to `>= 3`, not `> 3` (more than 3) which would exclude suppliers that supply 3 stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Count(*)` is going to include `Null` rows where as `count(distinct storecode)` will not. Try changing like this

```
select suppcode, count(distinct storecode) as StoresSupplied
from stocks
group by suppcode
having count(distinct storecode) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you just use the alias from the `select`:

```
select suppcode, count(distinct storecode) as StoresSupplied
from stocks
group by suppcode
having StoresSupplied > 3;
```